# Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Tags: permissions, software-installation, python, python3, pip

I've just installed Devuan GNU/Linux chimaera, and a bunch of packages manually. Also installed `python-is-python3`.

I now run, for example:

```
pip install pymonetdb
```

and I get:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pymonetdb
  Downloading pymonetdb-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 74.6/74.6 kB 867.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pymonetdb
Successfully installed pymonetdb-1.6.2
```

I'm wondering why I'm getting the message about site-packages not being writeable. Is it because I'm not the root user? But if that's the case, it shouldn't even *try* to write to some root-only folder. And if it's *not* because I'm non-root - what directory has inappropriate permissions, for me to fix (or have the root user fix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering why I'm getting the message about site-packages not being writeable.

It's because pip defaults to trying to install to the system-wide directories ("site-packages").

> Is it because I'm not the root user?

Yes.

> But if that's the case, it shouldn't even try to write to some root-only folder.

Indeed, it should not: It knows it's run by a non-root user, and knows it will therefore almost certainly fail, and should thus not default to trying to install to user-specific directories in this case (if not always). But - it still does try and fail and complain, which is silly, but that's what the developers thought they should be doing for some reason.

You could avoid the warning by running it like so:

```
pip install --user some_package_name
```

... but IMHO what should really happen is for someone to file a bug report about this and lean on the developers not to try and fail.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior kind of makes sense: you should practically never install software into the system-wide site-packages using pip, as that will lead to conflicts with your system package manager, unless you're in some kind of virtual environment where the path of that is bent to a writable location. This is actually independent of whether you're root or not.

Comment: But if that were the case, I should not be getting the error message about an _attempt_ to write to site-packages. Right?

Comment: To avoid this message, use `pip install --user`.

Comment: @einpoklum no, not right? Why try to write somewhere you can't? It's not like you'll be able to create a file in a directory that `stat` already told you you can't create a file in

Comment: @einpoklum you keep saying "error messages", but there's none of the usual trappings of Python exceptions and errors here. It's just a normal line of output without any indication that it's an error. I'd guess even the exit status would be zero.

Comment: @einpoklum there’s no pre-conceived notion of “root-only” directories. The best way to determine whether a directory is writable is to try writing.